# Swap Columns of Display 8086 Assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, emu8086

Everyone.

I want to flip the columns of the video screen/d/display in 8086 DOS emulator process. I am studying assembly language in school.

The question is swap the right vertical half of the screen with the left half of the vertical screen.

I want to pick the first column, replace it with the last one. Then pick the 2nd column, replace it with the 24th column and so on. I am having difficulty calculating the exact screen location. Also, I need two counters to store the value of the first and last column which will be incremented and decremented respectively. Also, I need two registers to swap the column values. There should be no clrscr function.

Here is my attempted code:

```
<pre>`
   [org 0x0100]


mov bx,1    ;dummy number
mov di,1     ;left-most column


Call FlipColumn

FlipColumn:


mov  ax, 0xb800               
mov  es, ax             ; point es to video base              
mov  al, 80             ; load al with columns per row               
mull  byte [di]       ; multiply with y position               
add  ax, [bx]        ; add x position               
shl  ax, 1              ; turn into byte offset               
mov  di, ax             ; point di to required location               

mov [es:di],ax     ;first row & first column element
mov dx,[es:di]

FlipColumn1:

mov di, 25
mov  ax, 0xb800               
mov  es, ax             ; point es to video base              
mov  al, 80             ; load al with columns per row               
mull  byte [di]       ; multiply with y position               
add  ax, [bx]        ; add x position               
shl  ax, 1              ; turn into byte offset               
mov  di, ax             ; point di to required location               

mov [es:di], dx

jne FlipColumn
ret

mov ax,0x4c00
int 21h

</pre>`
```

In this code, there are addressing issues and I can't configure how to swap those two columns. Please let me know if there is a different way to swap those memory locations.

Thanks.

Okay, friends, I modified this code like this:

```
<pre>`
[org 0x0100]

mov di, 1
mov si, 41

FlipColumn:

mov ax, 0xb800
mov es, ax

mov word ax, [es:1*80+1]
mov word bx, [es:41*80+1]
mov word [es:1*80+1], bx
mov word [es:41*80+1], ax

inc si
inc di
cmp si, 80
jbe FlipColumn 
mov ax, 0x4c00
int 21h`
</pre>
```

I wanted to use this statement:

```
       mov ax, [es:di*80+1]
       mov bx, [es:si*80+1]
```

But the debugger says, it is an addressing error. Any idea how can I increment and decrement the si and di so that I can swap the right and left sides of the display.

Comment: Common text mode on PC is 80x25, i.e. has 80 columns, not 25. And you want "swap left half with right half", but then "pick first column and exchange with last", and then "2nd column exchange with 24th" .. all of these are contradicting each other. If you want swap left and right half (vertical halves), you swap 1st column with 41th, 2nd with 42nd, ... and 40th with 80th column. If you want swap first vs last and then proceed toward centre, that's "mirror X" (but without mirroring character graphics itself, just chars). If you want to put screen "upside down", that's "mirror Y", etc...

Comment: and when programming in assembly, you have to be very precise, so sort first what you actually want to do, and then [edit] your question... maybe you will be able also to partly fix your code, once you will be able more clearly articulate, what you want to achieve. (btw the amount of bugs or misconceptions in your current code is about one misconception per every three lines or so (no swap happening for example), so don't hesitate to even throw it out several times and start over and over. Unless you are size/performance limited (you are NOT), assembly source can/should read quite clearly too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have modified my code but the output is not what I would like to get.

Comment: I tried hard-coding but the output is not what I want. Maybe I am not clarifying my question. I need to flip the video screen of the emulator from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to mirror. Fundamentally the two algorithms are the same but as @Ped7g pointed out, the specification is not really definitive.

> I want to pick the first column, replace it with the last one. Then pick the 2nd column, replace it with the 24th column and so on

```
            push    ds
            push    es
            mov     ax, 0xb800
            mov     ds, ax
            mov     es, ax
            xor     si, si
            mov     di, 158
            mov     cx, 25

       L0:  push    cx
            mov     cx, 40
            push    di
            push    si

       L1:  mov     ax, [di]
            mov     bx, [si]
            mov     [di], bx
            mov     [si], ax
            inc     si
            inc     si
            dec     di
            dec     di
            loop    L1

            pop     si
            pop     di
            add     si, 160
            add     di, 160

            pop     cx
            loop    L0

            pop     es
            pop     ds
```

Comment: you can remove all `es` related instructions, because this variant doesn't use `es` anywhere (contrary to the "string" instructions like `movsw`, which does use `es` implicitly). Setting up `ds` for this variant is enough.

Comment: Any particular reason for not swapping the 2 middle columns? Because that's what you get with a counter of 39. `mov cx, 39`

Comment: Although this code is very sub-optimal, I think it's perfect for the limited understanding of the OP. So +1 to you.

Comment: @SepRoland I did catch that in debug, but neglected to change it in the source before posting. It stood right out in my example using `DIR` as it turns out the year is right in the middle so, `2015` yielded `5012` and should have been `1502`

Answer (score 1):

Normally I wouldn't respond in this fashion as far too often all it equates to is doing the assignment for you, but you have put in a reasonable amount of effort so I'm going to give this example as it is a lot simpler than trying to explain why your methodology doesn't work. I've purposely left out comments as it will be incumbent upon you to use your emulator's debugger to understand the code and comment it before handing it in.

```
    push    ds
    push    es
    mov     ax, 0xb800
    mov     ds, ax
    mov     es, ax
    xor     si, si
    mov     di, 80
    mov     cx, 25

L0: push    cx
    mov     cx, 40

L1: mov     ax, [di]
    movsw
    mov     [si-2], ax
    loop    L1

    xchg    si, di
    add     di, 160
    pop     cx
    loop    L0

    pop     es
    pop     ds
```

There is probably going to be a couple of improvisations you're going to need to make to this NASM code, but I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: Did you debug it yourself, or try it? I don't believe it's doing "mirror x", it's swapping the left with right half of screens (by reading the source, didn't try it myself)... which is probably ok for OP to see how imprecise wording can lead to completely different result than expected. But the swap with `movsw` included is making it just more confusing for the mirror way, where the basic `mov` sequence makes more sense. :)

Comment: @Ped7g Yes I did assemble to a .COM and tested it in DosBox. I chose to flip a coin and go with paragraph two, but paragraph three contradicts it though largely due to swapping col 0 with 79 and then 1 with 23 didn't make a lot of sense. Ultimately I thought, if OP sees how a nested loop would be implemented, that might be a step in the right direction.